# Migrating to paket: use Windows only

Tags: .net, f#, paket

I've been trying to migrate my repository to use [paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/index.html) with [convert-from-nuget](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-convert-from-nuget.html) and in general everything goes smooth. The only problem I have is I noticed that my netstandard2.0 projects started to download non-Windows versions of some NuGet packages (e.g. those targeting Android or OS X - I don't need them).

After reviewing [this](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html) doc page I think it's enough to set `framework win{version}` in paket.dependencies file.

My question: what exactly shall I use as `{version}`? Is `framework win10` the right one?

Comment: What specific packages are you trying to use? I doubt you should have to specify a "win10" framework. It could be a problem with the package.

Comment: Also, does the build actually work? It could be that paket is downloading extra stuff that it doesn't need.

Comment: @Jwosty The package I've been having trouble with is SQLite. It causes paket to start downloading the entire internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually simpler than I thought. I found out that in my `*.fsproj` files there's a tag:

```xml
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

So I tried adding the following line to `paket.dependencies` and it worked:

```
framework: net5.0-windows
```

No idea however why it wasn't autogenerated by `paket convert-from-nuget`, but it's not a big deal.